# How do I merge two sorted arrays?

Tags: arrays, sorting, merge

Two arrays (`nums1` and `nums2`) of length `m` and `n` respectively have to be merged and the and be sorted in the array `nums1`. length of `nums1` is `m+n` and last `n` elements in `nums1` are `0`.
Not to be returned, `nums1` has to be modified.
**[LeetCode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-sorted-array/)**

##### Example

###### Input

```
nums1 = [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]
m = 3
nums2 = [2, 5, 6]
n = 3
```

###### Output `[1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6]`

###### Explanation

The arrays we are merging are `[1,2,3]` and `[2,5,6]`. The result of the merge is `[1,2,2,3,5,6]` with the underlined elements coming from nums1.

I have done the question but no idea why its not working.

```
var merge = function(nums1, m, nums2, n) {
    let j = 0
    for (let i = m; i < n; i++) {
      nums1[i] = nums2[j]
      j++
    } 
};
```

**Driven Code:**

```
let nums1 = [1,2,3,0,0,0], m = 3, nums2 = [2,5,6], n = 3
merge(nums1, m, nums2, n)
console.log(nums1)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: You've misunderstood the purpose of `m` and `n`. You should step through this in the debugger, and you'll quickly notice your loop is never entered.

Comment: please discuss algorithmic problems at leetcode. As I remember .net have Union operations or so

Answer (score 2):

You've misunderstood the purpose of `m` and `n`. You should step through this in the debugger, and you'll quickly notice your loop is never entered.

They're not first and last indices of the "zero region". They're the first index, and the count of zeros found after that (which is as long as the `num2` array that would be merged into `num1`. This would be more apparent if the names weren't as useless as `m` and `n`.

A performant solution to this would involve doing this in-place (in fact, the problem outline `requires` that you modify `num1` rather than make a new array).

You know both arrays are sorted, so "merging" only requires you pick the smallest element from each. The problem is that all your "free space" in `num1` (the `0`s) are located at the back, which makes it had to make room at the beginning of the array to insert elements from `num2`.

Instead, you can rely on this fact: An array that's sorted smallest-to-largest is also sorted when reversed, except from largest-to-smallest. While this may be obvious, it's the key trick: you fill `num2` starting from the end, and working towards the start. At every step, you replace a `0` (and eventually, the other numbers)`with the largest element from the "tail" of`num1`or`num2`.

Doing this all the way through gives you a time complexity of `O(n)` with no extra space used.

Answer (score 0):

Usse concat function of array and then sort function

e.g.

```
num1 = num1.concat(num2)
num1.sort()
```

OR

```
num1 = num1.concat(num2).sort()
```

Comment: It works when the nums1 is returned but if the function just modifies the nums1 the concatenation doesn't seems to work.

Comment: This doesn't modify `num1`, so it doesn't fit the problem outline.

Answer (score 0):

Do you searching something like this?

```
nums1 = [...nums1, ...nums2].sort().filter(i => i != 0);  
console.log(nums1);
```

Steps taken here:

1. First contact two array
2. Then sort the array in ascending order
3. Then remove `0` from the array

Check this out:

```
tempNums1 = nums1.slice(0, m);
tempNums2 = nums2.slice(0, n);
arr = [...tempNums1, ...tempNums2].sort((a,b) => { return a - b; });
nums1.splice(0, nums1.length);  
for(let i=arr.length - 1;i>=0;i--){
    nums1.unshift(arr[i]);
}
```

Here the hack is `splice` and `unshift` takes effect outside of the function scope

Updated:

```
 nums1.splice(m, nums1.length);// O(n)
 for(let j=0; j< n; j++){
     nums1.unshift(nums2[j]); // O(n)
 }
 nums1.sort((a, b) => a - b); // O(n log n)
```

Comment: This doesn't modify the array referenced by `nums1`, as required by the question: Not to be returned, nums1 has to be modified.

Comment: I have updated the code snippet. Is it working now?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but perhaps. It's missing a large point of this excersize, which it to operate in-place without space usage. "Follow up: Can you come up with an algorithm that runs in O(m + n) time?"

Comment: @Alexander I have updated another implementation ( I think memory consumption is lower now ). Check it out. At this moment, I haven't any idea to implement it in O(m+n) time complexity.

Comment: My answer explains it.

Answer (score 0):

There you go

```
public void merge(int[] nums1, int m, int[] nums2, int n) {
    
    if (n == 0) {
        return;
    }

   int i = m - 1;
   int j = n - 1;
    int k = nums1.length - 1;
    while (i >= 0 && j >= 0) {
        if (nums2[j] > nums1[i]) {
            nums1[k--] = nums2[j--];
        } else {
            nums1[k--] = nums1[i--];
        }
    }
    while (j >= 0) {
        nums1[k--] = nums2[j--];
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).